# Mobile performance of static helper class vs property

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm developing an app to be deployed over a range of devices (ranging from really powerful to the sort of thing you find at the back of a drawer that is as old as the hills).

In order to get the most out of the bottom range of device, I'm looking at refactoring the existing codebase.

I have a number of classes like this

```
public class MyHelperClass
{
    public static Foo MyHelper()
    {
        // do stuff
        return foo;
    }
}
```

The `stuff` is usually pretty trivial.

If the classes don't provide extension methods, is there a performance gain if I replace that class with something like

```
public class MyHelperClass
{
    public static Foo MyHelper
    {
        get
        {
            // do something
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

I have heard of performance gains on lower end processors using properties rather than static classes, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: Do notice that classes with only static methods should be marked as static

Comment: I think you'd be better off identifying bottlenecks and trying to solve those specific parts, rather than to update your entire codebase for the sake of a minor overall gain.

Comment: "using properties rather than static classes", where are you going to declared those properties but inside a (likely static) class?

Comment: Obligatory reading from Eric Lippert: [Link:
 Race Your Horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't thin that there is any gain. It could be a very tiny gain to replace an extension method with an instance method. In that case, the `this` reference would be passed via a CPU register, rather than as part of the function call on the memory stack. But that is a microscopic gain. And even that is a subject to compiler optimizations and the end result could be no gain at all in any case.

Note that property getters are nothing but methods. There are no properties in .NET. Your second piece of code would still be compiled as a static method:

```
public class MyHelperClass
{
    public static Foo get_MyHelper()
    {
        // do something
        return foo;
    }
}
```

This is literally what the compiler will do. If you reflect on your class, you will find the `get_MyHelper` static method there.